# How to filter drop down list box based upon another Field?

Tags: infopath, infopath-rules, cascading

I have drop down list box in Info Path form.

I have list which contains large number of data. I have used this list as data data source for Drop Down list field 
I'm filtering the value base on text box input value. 
I'm facing some case sensitive issue
e.g.:
If i enter Xyz then drop filter show only Xyz filter result but not showing the xyz

Please suggest something

Answer (score 0):

I fix the issue set filler like this:

```
 contains(translate(field1, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'),translate(xdXDocument:get-DOM()/my:myFields/my:Filter, "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", "abcdefghigklmnopqrstuvwxyz"))
```